# Python 3: how to compare multiple strings in one line of code?

Tags: python, string, comparator

I'm trying to make a category select (by text interface) in Python 3, and I was wondering how I can compare if multiple strings are not true, and then print something along the lines of "that is not a valid choice"

```
    input("what is your category choice?")
    if categoryChoice != "category1", "category 2", "category 3":
    print("not a valid choice")
```

I don't understand the syntax for having it check if any of category1, category2, category3, etc is true/false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Use `in` for containment tests.](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

```
categoryChoice = input("what is your category choice?")
if categoryChoice not in ("category1", "category 2", "category 3"):
    print("not a valid choice")
```

http://ideone.com/e6n0Rr

---

By the way, if you're using Python 2, you should *really* use `raw_input` instead of `input`.